# Zabbix - Set a group on top of System Status, without renaming

Tags: zabbix

I'm using Zabbix 3.0.1.

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnIzv.jpg

Goal: To place one host group above all the others for Dashboard -> System Status -> Host Group.

In this case a host group is named 1_bravo_cloud. 
But I'd like to have it named bravo_cloud without having it renamed to 1_bravo_cloud, in order to be on the top. The sorting is done in alphabetical order.

How is this possible, to have one host group above all the others to see the System Status, without renaming?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do that. Sorting will always be alphabetic.